# gwt+gxt+spring+mybatis+mysql the result is output

Tags: mysql, spring, gwt, mybatis, gxt

The program compiles without errors. I can not understand why the widget is not displayed.

GreetingServise

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("springGwtServices/greetingService")

public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {

    Greeting getGreeting(String text);

    void addGreeting(String author, String text);

    void updateGreeting(String author, String text);

    void deleteGreeting(String text);

    List<Greeting> getGreetings();

}
```

GreetingServiceAsync

```
public interface GreetingServiceAsync extends RemoteService {

    void getGreeting(String text, AsyncCallback<Greeting> async);

    void addGreeting(String author, String text, AsyncCallback<Void> async);

    void updateGreeting(String author, String text, AsyncCallback<Void> async);

    void deleteGreeting(String text, AsyncCallback<Void> async);

    void getGreetings( AsyncCallback<List<Greeting>> callback);
}
```

HelloGWT

```
public class HelloGWT implements IsWidget, EntryPoint {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloGWT.class);

    private static final GreetingMapper props = GWT.create(GreetingMapper.class);
    private static final GreetingServiceImpl impl = GWT.create(GreetingServiceImpl.class);

    private ContentPanel panel;


    public Widget asWidget() {
        if (panel == null) {
            ColumnConfig<Greeting, String> nameCol = new ColumnConfig<Greeting, String>(props.author(), 50, SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString("<b>Company</b>"));
            ColumnConfig<Greeting, String> symbolCol = new ColumnConfig<Greeting, String>(props.text(), 100, "Symbol");


            List<ColumnConfig<Greeting, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig<Greeting, ?>>();
            columns.add(nameCol);
            columns.add(symbolCol);


            ColumnModel<Greeting> cm = new ColumnModel<Greeting>(columns);


            ToolTipConfig config = new ToolTipConfig("Example Info", "This examples includes resizable panel, reorderable columns and grid state. Text selection is allowed.");
            config.setMaxWidth(225);
            ToolButton info = new ToolButton(ToolButton.QUESTION);
            info.setToolTipConfig(config);

            ListStore<Greeting> store = new ListStore<Greeting>(props.id());
            store.addAll(impl.getGreetings());

            final Grid<Greeting> grid = new Grid<Greeting>(store, cm);
            grid.setAllowTextSelection(true);
            grid.getView().setAutoExpandColumn(nameCol);
            grid.getView().setStripeRows(true);
            grid.getView().setColumnLines(true);
            grid.setBorders(false);
            grid.setColumnReordering(true);

            // Stage manager, turn on state management
            grid.setStateful(true);
            grid.setStateId("gridExample");

            // Stage manager, load previous state
            GridStateHandler<Greeting> state = new GridStateHandler<Greeting>(grid);
            state.loadState();

            SimpleComboBox<String> typeCombo = new SimpleComboBox<String>(new StringLabelProvider<String>());
            typeCombo.setTriggerAction(ComboBoxCell.TriggerAction.ALL);
            typeCombo.setEditable(false);
            typeCombo.setWidth(100);
            typeCombo.add("Row");
            typeCombo.add("Cell");
            typeCombo.setValue("Row");
            // we want to change selection model on select, not value change which fires on blur
            typeCombo.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<String>() {

                public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<String> event) {
                    boolean cell = event.getSelectedItem().equals("Cell");
                    if (cell) {
                        CellSelectionModel<Greeting> c = new CellSelectionModel<Greeting>();
                        c.addCellSelectionChangedHandler(new CellSelectionChangedEvent.CellSelectionChangedHandler<Greeting>() {

                            public void onCellSelectionChanged(CellSelectionChangedEvent<Greeting> event) {
                            }
                        });
                        grid.setSelectionModel(c);
                    } else {
                        grid.setSelectionModel(new GridSelectionModel<Greeting>());
                    }
                }
            });
            typeCombo.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

                public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
                }
            });

            ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
            toolBar.setEnableOverflow(false);
            toolBar.add(new LabelToolItem("Selection Mode: "));
            toolBar.add(typeCombo);

            VerticalLayoutContainer con = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
            con.add(toolBar, new VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));
            con.add(grid, new VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData(1, 1));

            panel = new ContentPanel();
            panel.setHeadingText("Basic Grid");
            panel.setPixelSize(600, 300);

            panel.addTool(info);

            final Resizable resizable = new Resizable(panel, Resizable.Dir.E, Resizable.Dir.SE, Resizable.Dir.S);
            panel.addExpandHandler(new ExpandEvent.ExpandHandler() {

                public void onExpand(ExpandEvent event) {
                    resizable.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
            panel.addCollapseHandler(new CollapseEvent.CollapseHandler() {

                public void onCollapse(CollapseEvent event) {
                    resizable.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
            panel.setWidget(con);

            // Enables quicktips (qtitle for the heading and qtip for the
            // content) that are setup in the change GridCellRenderer
            new QuickTip(grid);
        }

        return panel;
    }


    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // State manager, initialize the state options
        StateManager.get().setProvider(new CookieProvider("/", null, null, GXT.isSecure()));

        RootPanel.get().add(asWidget());

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        logger.info("Entering application.");
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.doIt();
        logger.info("Exiting application.");
    }

}
```

GreetingMapper

```
public interface GreetingMapper extends PropertyAccess<Greeting> {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM greetings WHERE text = #{text}")
    Greeting getGreeting(@Param("text") String text);

    @Select("INSERT INTO greetings (author, text) VALUES (#{author}, #{text})")
    void addGreeting(@Param("author") String author, @Param("text") String text);

    @Select("UPDATE greetings SET author = #{author} where text = #{text}")
    void updateGreeting(@Param("author") String author, @Param("text") String text);

    @Select("DELETE FROM greetings WHERE text = #{text}")
    void deleteGreeting(@Param("text") String text);

    @Select("SELECT * FROM greetings")

    List<Greeting> getGreetings();



    ModelKeyProvider<Greeting> id();

    ValueProvider<Greeting, String> author();

    ValueProvider<Greeting, String> text();
}
```

GreetingServiceImpl

```
@Service("greetingService")

public class GreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {


    @Autowired
    private GreetingMapper greetingMapper;

    @Override
    public Greeting getGreeting(String text) {
        return greetingMapper.getGreeting(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void addGreeting(String author, String text) {
        greetingMapper.addGreeting(author, text);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateGreeting(String author, String text) {
        greetingMapper.updateGreeting(author, text);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteGreeting(String text) {
        greetingMapper.deleteGreeting(text);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Greeting> getGreetings() {
        return greetingMapper.getGreetings();
    }
}
```

Greeting

```
public class Greeting extends BaseModelData implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private String author;
    private String text;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why in the browser does not display my table

Comment: GreetingServiceAsync should not extend RemoteService.

Comment: nothing not changed :(

Comment: do you even know how to use gwt rpc?? I really recommend you to start from plain gwt before you try using spring and mybatis...anyway your first problem here is the not displayed widget. try to get some really easy widget to work(maybe just an label?? public Widget asWidget() { return new Label("test");} )if this is not displayed neither then probably you should start from the bottom